# How to keep scale constant on two different graphs (2D) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

I am plotting the deflections of a bar at two different lengths with both their experimental and theoretical values.

I have two graphs that I need to create, but the axis need to have the same scale. I am currently plotting the two graphs on the same graph, but it looks cluttered and the report needs the second graph. I want it to be obvious to see the difference in the deflection of a bar on its edge and on its flat side.

Current Graph and Code:

```matlab
plot(L_4F,Load_Flat,'DisplayName','Flat: L/4 Exp','LineWidth', 1)

hold on

plot(y_L_4F,Load_Flat,'DisplayName','Flat: L/4 Theo','LineWidth', 1)

hold on

plot(L_2F,Load_Flat,'DisplayName','Flat: L/2 Exp','LineWidth', 1)

hold on

plot(y_L_2F,Load_Flat,'DisplayName','Flat: L/2 Theo','LineWidth', 1)

hold on



%% Plotting L/2

plot(L_4E,Load_Edge,'DisplayName','Edge: L/4 Exp','LineWidth', 1)

hold on

plot(y_L_4E,Load_Edge,'DisplayName','Edge: L/4 Theo','LineWidth', 1)

hold on

plot(L_2E,Load_Edge,'DisplayName','Edge: L/2 Exp','LineWidth', 1)

hold on

plot(y_L_2E,Load_Edge,'DisplayName','Edge: L/2 Theo','LineWidth', 1)

ldg = legend('Show');
ldg.Location = 'Best';
```

want to show the graphical difference but on separate graphs
[image: Graph]

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to the question. The above R and python tags are unnecessary

Comment: I just realized this, I apologize. This is my first post.

Comment: Use the same axis limits on both. See the documentation for `ylim` and `xlim`

Comment: You only need to call `hold on` **once** before plotting, and it will stay in place until you call `hold off`, which you should after all plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `linkaxes` function.  [Documented here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html)

Example using 2 subplots on 1 figure with only linking in the X-direction:

```
figure
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);plot(sin(0:.1:2*pi));
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);plot(cos(0:.1:2*pi));
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'x');
```

or x and y directions

```
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'xy');
```

Another Example of linking between 2 separate figures:

```
figure
plot(sin(0:.1:2*pi));
ax1 = gca;

figure;
plot(cos(0:.1:2*pi));
ax2 = gca;
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'xy');
```

Comment: No problem.  If this answered you question.  Please accept it as the solution